# How can I create an if statement on MATLAB that will replace pixels below a certain threshold to NaN?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, analysis

I'd like to replace the low intensity pixels so that I could create a mask that removes the noise. Matlab allows you to divide or subtract matrices with Not a Number values. I want to average out the noise.

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can post what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 4):

Changing pixels to NaN below a threshold: (no need for if, just use a logical condition)

```
Im(Im<threshold)=NaN;
```

Comment: When you say "Im" are you referring to the image or some kind of function? How would I go about with saving this new image under a different name

Comment: @AaronWoods, He is refering to [logical indexing](https://se.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) of the figure.

Comment: `Im` is your image, you can do `Im2=Im` then act on `Im2` if you want to save the old `Im`